# Divide by zero error encountered. T-SQL

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have the following T-SQL that I run in SQL 2012

```
SELECT machine_id, speed_gps_kph, odometer_total, event_timestamp, 
   1.0 * (speed_gps_kph - LAG(speed_gps_kph, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY machine_id ORDER BY event_timestamp)) /
   datediff(ss, LAG(event_timestamp, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY machine_id ORDER BY event_timestamp), event_timestamp)
FROM   Simple_speed
```

However, as the error indicates, I have an issue with dividing by zero.

There are quite a few posts and answers on this issue, but I am struggling to get then to work.

Comment: Is the question title the exact error? It's better to put that in the body of the question with words to the effect of "this is the error:"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple way to control for divide-by-zero errors, without repeating yourself, using `NULLIF(...,0)`:

```
SELECT machine_id, speed_gps_kph, odometer_total, event_timestamp, 
   1.0 * (speed_gps_kph - LAG(speed_gps_kph, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY machine_id ORDER BY event_timestamp)) 
   / NULLIF(datediff(ss, LAG(event_timestamp, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY machine_id ORDER BY event_timestamp), event_timestamp),0)
FROM Simple_speed
```

The expression will now return `NULL` for rows where the denominator is zero.